# Is there any way to control/route content by referrer value in Expression Engine?

Tags: expressionengine, referrer

Let’s say that I have a carousel on my index page.
Inside the template for index, it loads a particular channel, “Foo”

```
<div "slider">
  <ul class="slides">
  {exp:low_reorder:entries set="foo" dynamic="no"}
     <li class="foo_{entry_id}">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
         {foo_html}
         <style type="text/css">{foo_css}</style>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
  {/exp:low_reorder:entries}
  </ul>
   </div>
```

That channel, naturally, has a list of content items
I want the list of content items displayed to exclude one of the items in the channel if the referrer is not bing.

Can anyone show me the way that they would go about accomplishing that? I'm not getting any traction on the ellislab forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped up a plugin for you, which you can find [here](https://github.com/jonathanwkelly/ee-reeferrer)

You can wrap the item in a conditional using that plugin to check if it should be output.